# How to retrieve application log file path from WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties for an application installed on Websphere Application Server (WAS)?

Tags: java, bash, docker, log4j, websphere

I'm currently writing a bash script to copy log files from one host server to another host server. I have an application installed and running on a Websphere application server. The script would copy both the Server logs as well as application log to a remote staging directory. I can retrieve the server log files' path using `wsadmin`. I'm facing a challenge to retrieve the application log file path from `log4j.properties` under `WEB-INF/classes` directory.

Currently, I'm hard coding the log file path in a csv and from the csv, I'm retrieving it and using the command :

```
find <LOG_FILE_PATH> -type f -name $filename -newermt "$user_date_from" ! -newermt "$user_date_to"
```

Sample csv file content:

```
user@server_IP,AppServerName,LogFilePath,IdentifierToDifferentiateWhetherFileisServerLogOrAppLog
```

I want to do away with this csv file hard coding option because:

1. I know that `log4j.properties` already stores the log file paths.
2. I want to retrieve the log file path from `log4j.properties` instead at runtime, just to make sure that I do not have to update the csv hard coded value in case there is any change in `log4j.properties`.

Sample log4j.properties file content:

```
logFileLoc=<AbsoluteLogFilePath>

log4j.rootLogger=INFO,RollingAppender,stdout

log4j.appender.RollingAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.File=${logFileLoc}/<logFileName>.log
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.append=true
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{2}:%L - %m%n
```

So, I wonder if there exists any `wsadmin` like admin service available with log4j that can serve my purpose? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi ! Could you show us what you tried ? Please edit your question and add your code sample

Comment: Here you go! :)

Comment: Great ! Could also add a sample of `log4j.properties` ?

Comment: Added sample log4j.properties file content.

Comment: Sorry, I was swamped with work and didn't find time to answer your question. If you know the path of your property file, would this anwser help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38096496/2057091

Comment: Thanks @Aserre! It does. Looks like I will have to get some hands on with docker now.